# Reading NSDictionary by index

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a REST-api that returns the content from the call in an NSDictionary after parsing the JSON.

It is logged as this:

```
2013-04-07 23:43:25.008 MyApp[15133:c07] (
        {
        id = 1;
        name = "The best of NTNU";
        type = 1;
    },
        {
        id = 2;
        name = "Forever alone";
        type = 1;
    }
)
```

I want to have the first level of the dict as a NSDict that I can use. The problem is that no matter how I try to grab this (`valueForKey`, `objectForKey`) the app crashes.

According to the memory-inspector is the "children" of this NSDict [0] and [1], but I have no idea how to get ahold of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON is actually returning an NSArray of NSDictionaries, rather than a single NSDictionary.

To get the first level, you need to get the first index of the array:

```
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization ....
NSDictionary *firstLevel = json[0]; // or [json objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Ah, yeah, you're right. It happened because I was removing all the keys and values in the lower levels of the json, so I was left with an NSArray, but defined it as a NSDict. According to the documentation of NSJSONSerialization it should return a NSDict.

Comment: It depends on the structure of the JSON. Generally it would return an NSDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an `NSArray` (since there are no keys...), so you can access the first dictionary using the `objectAtIndex:` selector.

```
NSDictionary * dict0 = [array objectAtIndex:0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`.